# Parsing entry name from a log

Tags: bash, shell, parsing

Writing bash parsing scripts is my own personal nightmare, so here I am.

The server log format is below:

```
197 INFO    Thu Mar 27 10:10:32 2014
    seq_1_1..JobControl (DSWaitForJob): Waiting for job job_1_1_1 to finish
198 INFO    Thu Mar 27 10:10:36 2014
    seq_1_1..JobControl (DSWaitForJob): Job job_1_1_1 has finished, status = 3 (Aborted)
199 WARNING Thu Mar 27 10:10:36 2014
    seq_1_1..JobControl (@job_1_1_1): Job job_1_1_1 did not finish OK, status = 'Aborted'
```

From here I need to parse out the string which follows the format:

> Job **job_name** has finished, status = 3 (Aborted)

So from the output above I should get: job_1_1_1

What would the script for that look like if I get this server log as a certain command output?

Thanks xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -P`:

```
grep -oP '\w+(?= has finished, status = 3)' file
job_1_1_1
```

Comment: Yes, my answer implied that :)